# half transparent material when import xps file

Tags: import, transparency

[image]

I imported xps files and some of them have backface culling like issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0t5d.jpg

even resetting to default material didn't work
[image]

I also tried 
1. turn on and off backface culling option
2. flip normals
3. recalculate normals
4. change render engine

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check your alpha settings in the Material Settings? Depending on what kind of Alpha behaviour your Eevee Shader should have you need to change it. 
To reset it to default it needs to be at "Opaque" then it will draw as a solid.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved the problem on eevee. it seems the same option isn't available on cycles

Comment: no problem, cycles handles transparency a bit different, it's not "needed" there :)